# Trying to add Magento CMS content from a module setup script

Tags: magento

I was hoping to get some default CMS blocks installed from a modules setup scripts.  Googling around I concluded that the best way to do this would be to add a data/ directory to the module.  What I am trying is something like this, say module config.xml is :

```
<My_CustomMod>
     <version>0.1.0</version>
</My_CustomMod>
```

So I added a new file in `My/CustomMod/data/custommod_setup/data-install-0.1.0.php`

In there I have something like :

```
$cmsBlocks = array(
    array(
        'title'         => 'Footer Column One',
        'identifier'    => 'footer_column_one',
        'content'       => "stuff",
        'is_active'     => 1,
        'stores'        => 0
    ),
    array(
        'title'         => 'Footer Column Two',
        'identifier'    => 'footer_column_two',
        'content'       => "more stuff",
        'is_active'     => 1,
        'stores'        => 0
        )
);
foreach ($cmsBlocks as $data) {
    Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setData($data)->save();
}
```

I have cleared cache and expect to be able to look in the admin and see these newly created blocks but it does not work, I see none of the blocks in the CMS list, ie: no footer_column_one.  Any idea what else I should do to get this to work?  Is it necessary for me to add anything else to the config.xml?

Comment: Is the above code really working ?

Answer (score 0):

Try The following script. I think you have not set the store properly

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$staticBlock = array(
                'title' => 'My Static Block',
                'identifier' => 'my-static-block',
                'content' => 'Lorem ipsum',
                'is_active' => 1,
                'stores' => array(1)
                );

Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setData($staticBlock)->save();
```